# Como contabilizar quantos atendimentos meu cliente já fez?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-queryset

Não estou conseguindo contabilizar a quantidade de atendimentos que meu cliente fez.

```
class Atendimento(models.Model):
    tipo = models.ForeignKey(
        TipoAtendimento,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        blank=False,
        null=False,
        default=''
    )
    cliente = models.ForeignKey(
        Cliente,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        blank=False,
        null=False,
        default='Cliente'
    )
    funcionario = models.ForeignKey(
        Funcionario,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        blank=False,
        null=False,
        default=''
    )
    valor = models.DecimalField(
        verbose_name='Valor',
        max_digits=6,
        decimal_places=2,
        blank=False,
        null=False,
        default=0
    )
    gasto = models.DecimalField(
        verbose_name='Gastos',
        max_digits=6,
        decimal_places=2,
        blank=False,
        null=False,
        default=0
    )
    data = models.DateField(
        verbose_name='Data',
        blank=False,
        null=True,
        auto_created=False
    )
```

Como faço pra saber quantos atendimentos cada cliente fez?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Consegui achar a solução!!

Para quem estiver com a mesma dúvida, tem que usar Annotate, para contabilizar cadalinha da tabela, com Aggregate fica de forma geral, tipo se fosse um model de vendas o aggregate pegaria por exemplo a soma de todas, annotate contabiliza de cada linha da tabela.

Enfim..

A solução foi usar o annotate no model do cliente, como existe uma relação entre cliente e atendimento ficou assim:

```
from django.db.models import Sum
from clientes.models import Cliente

qtd_atendimentos = Cliente.objects.annotate(Sum('atendimento') # atendimento é o model que eu criei
```

Answer (score -2):

Boa tarde,

Precisa filtrar pelo cliente e usar .count() para contar

```
contagem = Atendimento.objects.filter(cliente=1).count()
```

onde, cliente=1, é o id da FK indicada na tabela Cliente

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

amigo acredito que vc vai ter q fazer algo assim,
atendimentos = Atendimento.objetcs.filter(cliente__id = "id do cliente")
print(atendimentos.count())

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).